# MS Access Update with Increment of Prior Record

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, record

I have an MS Access 2007 database that I need to create an update for. The table I am trying to update looks like this:

```
 CarID  WeekOf          NumDataPoints   NumWksZeroPoints
 3AA    May-14-2011     23              0
 7BB    May-14-2011     9               0

 3AA    May-21-2011     35              0
 7BB    May-21-2011     0               1

 3AA    May-28-2011     24  
 7BB    May-28-2011     0
```

I am processing the latest recordset of May-28-2011 and the gist is to update each car with the number of weeks its had no data points. I do this by checking the current week number of points and if it does have some points then the #WeeksZeroPoints gets set to zero, and if the current number of points is zero then i take the prior weeks count and increment by one. For my last week I would have input

```
  0
  2
```

So I have tried something like

```
UPDATE tblCars 
SET NumWksZeroPoints = IIF(NumDataPoints<>0, 0, (SELECT MAX(NumWksZeroPoints) AS wzp 
                                                 FROM tblCars AS f 
                                                 WHERE f.CarID=tblCars.CarID AND 
                                                       f.WeekEnding=#5/21/2011#) + 1
                       )
WHERE WeekOf=#5/28/2011#;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work like I thought it would. I think I have the concept down and most of the SQL, I just cant seem to make it work. This is against MS Access so some of the other tricks I know just don't work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Upvote of question is _after_ comment below that it's "design locked". Sometimes you just gotta know how to do the wrong thing the right way....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your sample data I ran the following

```
UPDATE tblcar AS c 
       INNER JOIN tblcar AS previous 
         ON c.carid = previous.carid 
SET    c.numwkszeropoints = Iif([previous].[NumWksZeroPoints] = 0, 0, 
                                   [previous].[NumWksZeroPoints] + 1) 
WHERE c.weekof =#5/28/2011 # 
         AND previous.weekof =#5/21/2011#;
```

The table afterwards looked like this

```
CarID WeekOf     NumDataPoints NumWksZeroPoints
----- ---------- ------------- -----------------
3AA   05/14/2011 23            0
7BB   05/14/2011 9             0
3AA   05/21/2011 35            0
7BB   05/21/2011 0             1
3AA   05/28/2011 24            0
7BB   05/28/2011 0             2
```

Basically the query does a self join back to the previous week, and the update the current week to the previous week's value + 1 if its not zero.

Comment: Never did an UPDATE query this way but it looks like it will work. I did however tweak it just slightly to SET c.NumWksZeroPoints = IIF(c.NumDataPoints<>0, 0, [previous].[NumWksZeroPoints] + 1) because the update should be based on the number of data points in the current week. I'll test and report what i see.

Comment: After testing this does what i need it to do. Thanks so much for your help. I learn something new everyday on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

You could (and some might say should) do this as a query, without updating the table.  If you are capturing the datapoints per week per car, your query can compute the number of weeks a car has had no data points using date math. What happens if someone inserts data for a car after you have run your update?  You end up with data that are inconsistent.

Comment: Well this is actually a rewrite of an old VB6 program that I'm doing with .NET. So all the tables and fields have to stay exactly the same otherwise the front end will not work. But you do bring up an interesting point. perhaps when i move on to rewriting the front end i will take that under advise. The database itself is probably not going to be updated in the wrong sequence. Im the only one that updates and maintains it. Everyone else just reads it. But it could happen.